# Why am I getting a line Feed Error when loading data via Powershell into clickhouse in Docker on Windows?

Tags: r, powershell, docker, clickhouse

I am attempting to load data into clickhouse in a docker container built in windows docker desktop. I have my mock data prepared in R, written as a csv and my table created in clickhouse (i'm ommiting the connections):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(clickhouse)
setwd("C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/testing_load")
my_df = data.table(datetime = as.character(c("2018-01-01 11:21:00", "2019-01-01 11:45:00")))
c(2018, 2019) %>%
  lapply(function(y) {
    print(y)
    fwrite(my_df[substr(datetime,1,4) == y],
              paste("test_",y,".csv"),
              row.names = F,
              col.names = F
           )
  })


dbSendQuery(con,
            paste(
              "CREATE TABLE test(
              datetime DateTime

              ) ENGINE = Log;"
            )
)
```

The data I am trying to load is huge, so this is just a sample to show the setup and why I am getting an error on the first line. I want to load the data using clickhouse client in powershell accessing the docker container as such:

```
#loop through files and load
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\testing_load"

foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName | Write-Host
    Import-Csv –Delimiter "," $f.FullName | Write-Host
    Get-Date | Write-Host    
    "Start loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
    docker run -it --rm --link chanalytics:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO test FORMAT CSV"
     Get-Date | Write-Host 
    "End loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
}
```

I added reading the data as well in case but I'm getting an error from clickhouse regarding the datetime time. I have tried switching to positxc in R and it makes no difference. I can't tell but feel that this is a very simple thing I am not understanding. Below is the error I get:

[image]

Opening excel I can see that the datetime is fine in date format. Any suggestions on what might be going on?

Comment: I know nothing about ClickHouse but note that `Write-Host` is for writing to the _display_, not for writing _data_ (though an outside process would see `Write-Host` output via stdout too). How is the `docker`-launched process supposed to receive input? You're not piping any data to it.

Comment: the error seems to be saying that your input contains a literal string, not a `LF` char. have you verified where that text is coming from?

Comment: Hey Lee, well I can confirm that the files are there, in this case two files I am looping through to read and load into clickhouse. I opened them in excel and can see a datetime format, as you can see in the R code I am simply using one column called datetime.

Comment: @LoF10: Your PowerShell code has no connection with the `docker` command you're issuing, giving that you're not providing stdin input to it (which in PowerShell requires a pipe (`|`)), so let me ask again: How do you expect anything you're doing in your PowerShell code to reach the `INSERT INTO test FORMAT CSV` command?

Comment: @LoF10: If you had engaged in a _dialogue_ instead of first ignoring feedback and then responding with an insult, you would have realized that I was pointing you in the right direction all along - the need to provide _stdin_ input to the `docker` command by way of a _pipe_. I didn't understand the specifics of your `docker` command, but I knew that something was missing. A simple clarification on your part - needing to pipe the _contents_ of your file to the `docker` command - would have solved this problem much sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue:

```
#loop through files
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\testing_load"

foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName | Write-Host
    Get-Date | Write-Host    
    "Start loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
    cat $f.FullName | docker run -i --rm --link chanalytics:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m --host chanalytics --query="INSERT INTO tpep FORMAT CSV"
     Get-Date | Write-Host 
    "End loading" + $f.FullName | Write-Host
}
```